# Git rewind master branch to specific commit in master's history

Tags: git

I have the following recent history in my git repo.

```
* 7661a06 (HEAD, origin/devConsolidate, devConsolidate) Fix seg fault; OCBA intermediary compares by value() now also
| * 0bbe038 (origin/master, master) Flawed work no seedShift
|/  
* 62fe9db Turn on OCBA_DEBUG; nan/inf values in OCBA prior to crash
* 71298c8 Turn on OCBA (non-intermediary); seg fault occurs
* 3693904 No OpenMP, no OCBA; no memory leaks on valgrind
* 9d5686c Disable OpenMP threads
* 80bbc3b Debug (-O0) build now throws exception also
* e148013 Post convert simulation4_NEJMdisutilities [] to at()
* 66cfba9 Post convert OCBA [] to at()
* 32db3be Pre convert OCBA [] to at()
* 4a9f25b Prep for debugging
* 907e88b Found error (vector out of bounds); need to fix from here
* ca6c639 Implement elapsed, iteration, and max time in OCBA
* db68c15 Fix SEG FAULT; OCBA now working (with intermediary)
* f1c6f05 GA now uses OCBA; GA/OCBA params from config file; produces SEG FAULT
| * 3b16dcf (origin/genCRNgraph, genCRNgraph) Generate QALYs test and control independent-sampling
|/  
*   001eff2 Merge branch 'OCBAdev'
```

All the commits subsequent to (descendants of) `f1c6f05` were done to debug a problem.  In hindsight, I should have create a separate branch to do this debugging, but I did it all in `master`.  Now, in commit `7661a06`, I have fixed the bug.

I want to move (rewind?) the `master` branch (or pointer) so that it is located at commit `f1c6f05`.  After I do this, then I can generate a patch from the diff between commits `7661a06` and `62fe9db` and apply it to `f1c6f05`.  As a result, a portion of my git log should look like this:

```
* 7661a06 (origin/devConsolidate, devConsolidate) Fix seg fault; OCBA intermediary compares by value() now also
| * 0bbe038 Flawed work no seedShift
|/  
* 62fe9db Turn on OCBA_DEBUG; nan/inf values in OCBA prior to crash
           .
           .        
           .
* db68c15 Fix SEG FAULT; OCBA now working (with intermediary)
| * <HASH> (HEAD, origin/master, master) Fix problem and rewind master
|/
* f1c6f05 GA now uses OCBA; GA/OCBA params from config file; produces SEG FAULT
| * 3b16dcf (origin/genCRNgraph, genCRNgraph) Generate QALYs test and control independent-sampling
|/  
*   001eff2 Merge branch 'OCBAdev'
```

What commands would I use to achieve all of this?  Specifically, how would I: (1) move master, (2) generate the patch, and (3) apply the patch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have already pushed `master` to `origin` (`origin/master` is at `0bbe038`), this will cause problems for anyone who has already fetched or pulled from `origin` since your push. So, you may need to communicate and coordinate with others what is going on so they can adjust as necessary.

With that in mind, though, here's how you would do it:

1) Move master back to `f1c6f05`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard f1c6f05
git push -f origin master
```

2+3) Rather than generating and applying a patch, assuming `7661a06` is the only relevant commit for your fix, you can simply do this:

```
git checkout -b bug-fix-branch master
git cherry-pick 7661a06
```

It's possible you may get some minor conflicts, depending on exactly what all the "debug" commits actually did, and whether they touched anything nearby what the `7661a06` commit changed, but these should be pretty easy to fix. Once that's done, do this to merge that change back into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge bug-fix-branch
git branch -d bug-fix-branch    # optional, maybe not desired
git push origin master
```

At this point, everyone else will need to fetch/pull the new `master` branch, and restart whatever work they have pending.

If the disruption to others is unacceptable, you can alternatively do this:

```
git checkout master
git revert f1c6f05..62fe9db
git push master
```

This will create new commits on master that undo the effects of all those "debug" commits, but won't actually remove them from history. So the ending content of your working directory should end up looking the same, but the history will look very different. In this case, there should be no disruption to others, so depending on your environment/workflow, this is probably the better option, but it does document for posterity the mistakes made, and may cause confusion/problems down the road if you ever need to use `git bisect` to track down new bugs or something...

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that this is a private repo.  There are no other developers.

Comment: Ok, so in that case, `origin` is either a "backup" repo or just another copy of the repo on another system (desktop vs. laptop maybe)? In either case, then, the hassle from using `git reset` and `git push -f` should be fairly minimal. However, you might run into an additional bump in the road if `origin` is not a bare repo - you may need to make sure that `master` is *not* checked out there before you push.

Comment: `origin` is just a backup that I store on a private github repo.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard f1c6f05
git rebase --onto master 62fe9db devConsolidate
```

If you are happy with the history of `devConsolidate` after that:

```
git checkout master
git merge devConsolidate
```

Comment: Will this delete any of my commits?  (I don't want it to.)

Comment: It's really difficult to *delete* commits with Git. All those commits will still be there accessible via their hashes (until they're garbage collected which won't happen for at least 30 days). Rewriting history (`git reset` and `git rebase` in this case) always creates a new version of the history and moves a pointer (a branch) to the new one. If you want a reference to where you were before a `git reset` or `git rebase`, just drop a branch there: `git branch foo`. If you forget to do so, you can follow the history of branches with `git reflog`.